# how to convert array to object in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have an array of object as given with unknown number of array elements:

```
               { "content": [
                    {
                        "_id": "refbooks",
                        "total": 189,
                        "published": 189,
                        "created": 0,
                        "approved": 0,
                        "rejected": 0,
                        "sent_for_approval": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "weblinks",
                        "total": 1911,
                        "published": 1899,
                        "created": 10,
                        "approved": 2,
                        "rejected": 0,
                        "sent_for_approval": 0
                    },.................]}
```

I want to convert it to an object like given:

```
                    { "content": {
                    {
                        "_id": "refbooks",
                        "total": 189,
                        "published": 189,
                        "created": 0,
                        "approved": 0,
                        "rejected": 0,
                        "sent_for_approval": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "weblinks",
                        "total": 1911,
                        "published": 1899,
                        "created": 10,
                        "approved": 2,
                        "rejected": 0,
                        "sent_for_approval": 0
                    },.................}}
```

I tried using $unwind, but I did't get my required output.
How to implement this inside aggregation pipeline in MongoDB?

I'm using Mongo version 3.4.

Comment: That's an impossible setup... Not sure what you mean. Whenever you have a collection of things it has to be wrapped in an array...?

Comment: your expected result is not a valid object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
{
            $project: {
                "content": {
                    "$arrayToObject": {
                        "$map": {
                            "input": "$content",
                            "as": "el",
                            "in": {
                                "k": "$$el._id",
                                "v": "$$el"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the second one is not a proper object format you need a key value pare for make object

```
{ "content": {
                   "key1":{
                        "_id": "refbooks",
                        "total": 189,
                        "published": 189,
                        "created": 0,
                        "approved": 0,
                        "rejected": 0,
                        "sent_for_approval": 0
                    },
                   "key2":{
                        "_id": "weblinks",
                        "total": 1911,
                        "published": 1899,
                        "created": 10,
                        "approved": 2,
                        "rejected": 0,
                        "sent_for_approval": 0
                    }}}
```

Comment: Yeah, like that

Comment: @LabeebShareef i guess you already find the answer there is another way for doing same by using underscore.js   https://underscorejs.org/#groupBy