# Return a single object from Aggregate Method Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have a dynamic model 'Dialog' model in which a field called lecture is sometimes available sometimes not, and the Lecture model is defined on different nodejs server. I want to populate the result of the lecture in the dialog as well. so I try using populate but it gives a Schema not register error. So I am trying to using $lookup to join data from different collections. But, the Aggregate method returns an array and I need an object. I have tried accessing using arr[0] using index zero. But I have a method defined on the Dialog model. when I try accessing it throws an error.

```
  const resp = await DialogModel.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                $and: query
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "lectures",
                localField: "lecture",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "lectureDetail"
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$lectureDetail",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Here is current out:

```
[
  {
    _id: 60ab86e1671c602015741955,
    lecture: 607d4d3de9b8be1f29e56e94,
    lectureDetail: {
      _id: 607d4d3de9b8be1f29e56e94,
      course: 6076ba3a01060327b3231a3c,
      owner: 607434cd63b75949f61cc065,
      name: 'Lecture 11',
      startDate: 2021-05-24T07:00:00.000Z,
      endDate: 2021-05-24T08:00:00.000Z
    }
  }
]
```

Here is the expected output:

```
{
  _id: 60ab86e1671c602015741955,
  lecture: 607d4d3de9b8be1f29e56e94,
  lectureDetail: {
    _id: 607d4d3de9b8be1f29e56e94,
    course: 6076ba3a01060327b3231a3c,
    owner: 607434cd63b75949f61cc065,
    name: 'Lecture 11',
    startDate: 2021-05-24T07:00:00.000Z,
    endDate: 2021-05-24T08:00:00.000Z
  }
}
```

If I try getting access using the index, and call method on it. method Defined on my Model through an error of is not a function.

Here is my query. Kindly guide me on how to solve this issue.

Comment: can you show the aggregation results? and expected output?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the expected output and current output.

Comment: `lectureDetail` is an object, you can directly access it.. and when you show us, please remove unnecessary fields for better eye sight

Comment: I am talking about as a whole aggregate return list, I want it to be an object.

Comment: What is the problem you face when fetching the first object?

Comment: check this up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52987808/how-to-convert-array-to-object-in-mongodb

Comment: check this up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52987808/how-to-convert-array-to-object-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate method always returns result in form of array rather than single object.

You can access your first object by ==> resp[0]

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. But On My Dialog object, I have a method. When i try to call it on this object it throws an error. Error is " is not a function"